# Is file path valid in gulp src

Tags: gulp, task

I'm looking for solution which will help me to find is file path valid. And if file path not valid to show some error.

```
gulp.task("scripts-libraries", ["googlecharts"], function () {
    var scrlibpaths = [
            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "./libs/AdminLTE-2.3.0/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
            "./libs/AdminLTE-2.3.0/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js",
            "./libs/adminLTE-app.js",
            "./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
            "./node_modules/jquery.inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js",
            "./node_modules/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js",
            "./node_modules/bootstrap-checkbox/dist/js/bootstrap-checkbox.min.js",
            "./node_modules/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js",
            "./node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js",
            "./node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js",
            "./node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-latest.js",
            "./node_modules/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.min.js",
            //"./src/jquery.multiselect.js"
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < scrlibpaths.length; i++) {
        if (scrlibpaths[i].pipe(size()) === 0) {
            console.log("There is no" + scrlibpaths[i] + " file on your machine");
            return;
        }
    }

    return gulp.src(scrlibpaths)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat("bundle.libraries.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.path.dist + "/js"));
});
```

So how can i make this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`glob` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to check if the paths/globs you pass to `gulp.src()` refer to existing files. Gulp itself uses `glob` internally via [`glob-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-stream) so this should be the most reliable option.

Here's a function that uses `glob` and that you can use as a more or less drop-in replacement for the regular `gulp.src()`:

```
var glob = require('glob');

function gulpSrc(paths) {
  paths = (paths instanceof Array) ? paths : [paths];
  var existingPaths = paths.filter(function(path) {
    if (glob.sync(path).length === 0) {
        console.log(path + ' doesnt exist');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
  return gulp.src((paths.length === existingPaths.length) ? paths : []);
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
return gulpSrc(scrlibpaths)
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(concat("bundle.libraries.js"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.path.dist + "/js"));
```

If any of the paths/globs in `srclibpaths` doesn't exist a warning is logged and the stream will be empty (meaning no files will be processed at all).

Comment: This is what I need. And this was right solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since `gulp` is just like any other `node` script you can use [`accessSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_accesssync_path_mode) to check whether the file exists (I assume you probably want to be synchronous).

```
var fs = require('fs');
scrlibpaths.map(function(path) {
    try {
        fs.accessSync(path);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("There is no " + path + " file on your machine");
    }
});
```